# Try to get qty for a single product issue

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, quantity

I try to get qty for a single product which came from o grouped product after a finish my order

In my observer i can take the product name, id,price, attribute id and so on but i can't take the qty

I have the fallowing code in my observer:

```
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
     foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
             $ProdustIds = $item->getProductId();
     // product name
     $proName[] = $item->getName(); 


    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($ProdustIds);

     $productAttributeId = $customProduct->getData('attribute_set_id');

    //get attribute set name for each product
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $attributeSet = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
    $attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->get($productAttributeId);
    $attribute_set_name = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
    $attribute_name = strtolower($attribute_set_name);

    //get prodcut price
    $productAttributePrice = $customProduct->getData('price');
    //product qty
    $productAttributeQty = $customProduct->getData('qty');
    $proQty[] = $item->getQty();
```

I  already tried  with  `$productAttributeQty = $customProduct->getData('qty')`; and

```
$proQty[] = $item->getQty()
```

But is not working.

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
     foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
             $ProdustIds = $item->getProductId();
     // product name
     $proName[] = $item->getName(); 


    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($ProdustIds);

     $productAttributeId = $customProduct->getData('attribute_set_id');

    //get attribute set name for each product
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $attributeSet = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
    $attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->get($productAttributeId);
    $attribute_set_name = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
    $attribute_name = strtolower($attribute_set_name);

    //use below to get ordered qty
     echo $item->getQtyOrdered();

    //get prodcut price
    $productAttributePrice = $customProduct->getData('price');
    //product qty
    $productAttributeQty = $customProduct->getData('qty');
    $proQty[] = $item->getQty();
```

Comment: it gave me the stock qty. how can i get the qty that i buy in the cart for one product?

Comment: what i try to do, it to take the qty for each product that was add in the cart after the order is ready

Comment: up[dated answer please check it

Comment: it donsn't work. i am on magento 2. i think that;s is the problem

Comment: the solution was $item['qty_ordered']. Thank you very much anyway